# Join 2" aluminum pipe between two 4"x4" treated lumber?

Tags: wood, pipe, fence

How can I attach an aluminum pipe to (2) 4"x4" pieces of pressure-treated lumber? The pipe would act as a rail.

It would be like this:

[image]

This is another example, but with a top rail:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about new or existing construction?  If new, why not just drill holes in the 4" posts and insert the pipe as you build?

Comment: This is what I would do too, but it truly depends in the wood used for the posts. If it is pressure treated, it will eat up the aluminum.

Comment: The wood is pressure-treated.

Comment: Can you better define "attach", and the range of acceptable options?  What kind of force does it need to handle?  Is it OK for it to rotate?  What can be visible?  The picture just likes like pipe going into a hole, which some people wouldn't even call attaching.  Do you have a specific issue you're looking to address (question is not so much how to attach the pipe, but how to keep an aluminum pipe from corroding in pressure treated wood)?  There are endless ways to attach a pipe to a post.  Creating a "list" generally isn't considered a good question for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drill a hole. Put in a [PVC end cap](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Charlotte-Pipe-2-in-PVC-Sch-40-Socket-Cap-PVC021161600HD/203811678). Insert the aluminum pipe into the PVC end cap. Only trick is making sure you get exactly the right size PVC - inner diameter of PVC should be same size as (or ever so slightly bigger than) outer diameter of pipe.